# how to fetch json with foreach in angular2

Tags: json, angular, angular2-template

Hi guys I'm working on Angular application and I would like some help to fetch the data from the json. I've got my conpoments.ts with my method but it is not working. I included the json file. please help me to display the data on html page.Thank you

```
label: "car"
manufacture:Array(3)
{id: "1", label: "name", question: "", type: "type", value: {…}}
{id: "2", label: "name", question: "", type: "type", value: {…}}
{id: "3", label: "name", question: "", type: "type", value: {…}}


import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { ManufactureService } from '../../services/ManufactureService/manufacture.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'body-content',
  templateUrl: './body.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./body.component.less']
})
export class BodyComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public 
  manufactureService:ManufactureService) { }
  async ngOnInit() {

  const [err,data] = await  this. manufactureService.getManufature('car','man').toPromise()

   if (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return false
    } 

    showCar(data){
    data.forEach(el=>{
      this.manufactureService.getManufature.push();
    })
  }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

import [`HttpClientModule`](https://angular.io/guide/http) in app.module.ts

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private manufactureService: ManufactureService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this. manufactureService.getManufature(subscribe(data => {
      console.log("results :", data)
      data.forEach(el=>{
        this.manufactureService.getManufature.push();
    })
    },error => {
      console.log("Error :", error)
    });
  }
}
```

Service Function :

```
// import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {} 

getManufature(){
    return this.http.get('path or url to JSON'); 
}
```